# Unable to find record by id in mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, meanjs

I am trying to find record by id but it not getting done

```
var id = req.param('id');
var item = {
    '_id': id
}
videos.find(item, function(error, response) {});
```

I have give a valid id but still it is not fetching,can anyone suggest help,please.

Comment: You should use [`findById`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a callback provided to `find()` but in your code above, it has no executable statements. Instead of this:

```
videos.find(item, function(error, response) {});
```

...do something like this:

```
videos.find(item, function(error, response) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error); // replace with real error handling
    return;
  }
  console.log(response); // replace with real data handling
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use callbacks for error handling. And **find()** returns array. If you need to find user by unique key (in this case _id) you must use **findOne()**

```
router.get('/GetVideoByID/:id',function(req,res){
    var id = req.params.id;
    var video = {
        '_id' : id
    }
    videos.findOne(video,function(err,data){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log("Video found");
            res.json(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: When using the mongoose module they suggest using findById() rather than findOne(). You can have a look at the documentation http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById

Comment: Thank you for correcting me @LukeKroon. But I want to know why to use findById() and not findOne() ? Is there difference between execution time of these queries?

Comment: According to the documentation findbyId() triggers the findOne() hooks except for how it treats undefined, i.e. findOne(undefined) returns an arbitrary document and findById(undefined) translates into findOne({_id:null}) which returns nothing. Its a fail safe by the looks of it. :)